# Issue with Castor XML Upgrade: MarshalException - ValidationException

Tags: java, xml, gzip, unmarshalling, castor

I recently upgraded from Castor version 0.9.53 to Castor-XML version 1.4.1 in my Java project. After making this update, I removed the old Castor version (0.9.53) from my classpath and added the new Castor-XML 1.4.1 library.

However, I'm now encountering an issue when trying to unmarshal XML data using the new Castor-XML library. Specifically, I'm getting the following error:
org.exolab.castor.xml.MarshalException: ValidationException: Empty ID value encountered{File: [not available]; line: 1; column:12 }
This error is thrown at the line

```
reader.parse(source);
```

Additional Code:

I am using the following code to unmarshal XML data from a gzip-compressed file:

```
FileInputStream gzipReader = new FileInputStream("abc.xml.gz");
Reader reader = ZipInputStream(gzipReader);
abc = (Abc) Abc.unmarshal(reader);
```

Interestingly, I did not encounter this issue when using Castor version 0.9.53.

Question:

1.Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error?

2.Is there something specific I need to do differently when using Castor-XML 1.4.1 compared to Castor 0.9.53?

3.Could the issue be related to unmarshaling from a gzip-compressed file using the provided code?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: para 1.2.3.3 (https://castor-data-binding.github.io/castor/reference-guides/1.4.1/html/XML%20data%20binding.html) says ID is required.  It is probably a change in the library.

Comment: I don't have id, still how can I resolve error ?

Comment: See https://helpdesk.castoredc.com/manage-your-study/customize-record-ids